# Inserting array of data into multiple rows of database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert an array of data

**form.php**

```
<form name="users" method="post" action="order_submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();" id="inv_form">
    <div class="formSep">
        <select name="company" onChange="showSubcat(this);">
            <option value="">Company</option>
            <?php
              $s1 = mysql_query("select * from leads where lead_customer='Lead' ")
                      or die (mysql_error());
              while($s2 = mysql_fetch_array($s1))
              {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $s2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $s2['company']; ?></option>
            <?php
              }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="formSep">

       <table class="table invE_table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th></th>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th>Unit</th>
                   <th>Unit Cost ($)</th>
                   <th>Qty</th>
                   <th>Tax (%)</th>
                   <th>Total ($)</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr class="inv_row">
                   <td class="inv_clone_row"><i class="icon-plus inv_clone_btn"></i></td>
                   <td><input type="text" class="span12" name="invE_item[]" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" class="span12" name="invE_description[]" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" class="span12 jQinv_item_unit" name="invE_unit_cost[]" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" class="span12 jQinv_item_qty" name="invE_qty[]" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" class="span12 jQinv_item_tax" name="invE_tax[]" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" readonly class="span12 jQinv_item_total" name="invE_total[]" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="last_row">
                   <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       <p class="clearfix">Subtotal: <span class="invE_subtotal">$<span>0.00</span></span></p>
                       <p>Tax: <span class="invE_tax">$<span>0.00</span></span></p>
                       <p>Discount: <span class="invE_discount">$<span>0.00</span></span></p>
                       <p><strong>Balance: <span class="invE_balance">$<span>0.00</span></span></strong></p>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </tbody> 
       </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here  `invE_item[]`, `invE_description[]`, `invE_unit_cost[]`, etc. are the array, I mean dynamically one can add as many as items and its details.

In my **order_submit.php** page

```
<?php

  error_reporting(0);
  include("connect.php");
  include("admin_auth.php"); 

  if(isset($_POST['save']))
  {

      $company = $_POST['company'];
      $contact_person = $_POST['contact_person'];
      $billing = $_POST['billing_address'];
      $shipping = $_POST['shipping_address'];
      $reference = $_POST['reference'];
      $t_c = $_POST['t_c'];
      $payment = $_POST['payment'];
      $ship_in = $_POST['ship_inst'];
      $validity = $_POST['validity'];
      $currency = $_POST['currency'];
      $order_for = $_POST['order_for'];
      $assigned_to = $_POST['assigned_to'];
      $item = $_POST['invE_item'];
      $unit = $_POST['invE_description'];
      $price = $_POST['invE_unit_cost'];    
      $qty= $_POST['invE_qty']; 
      $tax = $_POST['invE_tax'];    
      $total = $_POST['invE_total'];    

      $sql = mysql_query("insert into orders (order_id, company_id, contact_person, billing_address, shipping_address, reference, t_c, payment, shipping_inst, validity, order_for, currency, assigned_to, last_modified, order_quote) values ('', ".$company.", '".$contact_person."', '".$billing."', '".$shipping."', '".$reference."', '".$t_c."', '".$payment."', '".$ship_in."', ".$validity.", '".$order_for."', '".$currency."', '".$assigned_to."', NOW(), 'Order')");

      $last_id = mysql_insert_id();

      $msql = "insert into order_line_items (id, order_id, company_id, item, unit, unit_cost, quantity, tax, total) values ('', ".$last_id.", ".$company.", '".$item."', '".$unit."', ".$price.", ".$qty.", ".$tax.", ".$total.")";


      $l1 = mysql_query($msql) or die (mysql_error());  
  }
%>
```

I want to insert each item in different row with `$last_id` like this:

[image]

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and `mysql_*` is deprecated. You should use PDO or `mysqli_*` with prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah, i am doing that. But how can i achieve this?

Comment: _Yeah, i am doing that_ ... what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Actually I am correcting my code using PDO and mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @user2823107: I think this is what Mr. Smith is hinting at: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using PDO, you can [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) statements and when [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)uting them you can supply the needed parameters.

So inserting into `orders` could look like this

```
$insertOrder = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO orders (company_id, contact_person, ...) 
    VALUES (:company_id, :contact_person, ...)');
$insertOrder->execute(array(
    ':company_id' => $_POST['company'],
    ':contact_person' => $_POST['contact_person'],
    ...
));
```

This might look more complex than your escaping + query but once you understand it, it is quite more easy to maintain.

Now [`lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) will get you exactly that and again using `prepare()` and `exec()` will do the other inserts. By wrapping the latter in a loop you can manage the handling of various (unknown) items. The only thing you need to watch for is that all keys fit together. Meaning `invE_item[x]` is for the same row as `invE_unit[x]`

```
$orderId = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$insertOrderItem = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO order_line_items (order_id, item, unit, ...) VALUES (:order_id, :item, :unit, ...)');
foreach ($_POST['invE_item'] as $i=>$item) {
    $insertOrderItem->execute(array(
        ':order_id' => $orderId,
        ':item' => $item,
        ':unit' => $_POST['invE_unit'][$i],
        ...
    ));
}
```